# How to implement additon assignment operator i.e. "+=" in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have input xml like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<data>
    <point>
        <distance>0.000</distance>
    </point>
    <point>
        <distance>10.000</distance>
    </point>
    <point>
        <distance>17.000</distance>
    </point>
    <point>
        <distance>25.000</distance>
    </point>
</data>
```

I want to apply an xslt and get output xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<point>
    <cumulDistance>0.000</cumulDistance>
</point>
<point>
    <cumulDistance>10.000</cumulDistance>
</point>
<point>
    <cumulDistance>27.000</cumulDistance>
</point>
<point>
    <cumulDistance>52.000</cumulDistance>
</point>
```

so each node value in output is sum of values coming from previous nodes.

I am writing xslt like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:variable name="totalDistance" select="0.0"/>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="data/point">
            <point>
                <cumulDistance>
                    <!--$totalDistance = $totalDistance + distance-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="$totalDistance"/>
                </cumulDistance>
            </point>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The commented statement is what I want to implement. In normal programming language I can achieve this by "+=" operator i.e. totalDistance+=distance. But in xslt it is not possible because I read that xsl variables works more like a constant and are immutable.

Can someone please tell the way to handle this in xslt.

Thanks.

Comment: The closest in XSLT 3 would be an accumulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop. Just use templates and the sum()-function to summarize the values of preceding siblings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data/point"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="point">
        <point>
                <cumulDistance>
                   <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::*/distance) + distance"/>
                </cumulDistance>
            </point>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3 you can use an accumulator as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="#all"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="accumulated-distance" as="xs:decimal?" initial-value="()">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="data" select="0"/>
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="point/distance" select="$value + xs:decimal(.)"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:template match="point/distance">
      <cumulDistance>{accumulator-before('accumulated-distance') => format-number('0.000')}</cumulDistance>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQG

In XSLT 1 sibling recursion should do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="point[1]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="point">
      <xsl:param name="accumulated-distance" select="0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="new-distance" select="$accumulated-distance + distance"/>
      <xsl:copy>
          <cumulDistance>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number($new-distance, '0.000')"/>
          </cumulDistance>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::point[1]">
          <xsl:with-param name="accumulated-distance" select="$new-distance"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaQG/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are limited to XSLT 1.0, I would suggest you use a named recursive template for this, for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <root>
        <xsl:call-template name="accumulate">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="point"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="accumulate">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="prev-distance" select="0"/>
    <xsl:if test="count($nodes)">
        <xsl:variable name="cumulDistance" select="$prev-distance + $nodes[1]/distance"/>
        <point>
            <cumulDistance>
                <xsl:value-of select="$cumulDistance"/>
            </cumulDistance>
        </point>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="accumulate">
            <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="prev-distance" select="$cumulDistance"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does exactly what you asked for, i.e. add a new value to an already accumulated total. This is *much* more efficient than using:

```
sum(preceding-sibling::point/distance) + distance
```

which sums the same nodes over and over again.

Comment: If xslt 1.0 this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  >
  
  <xsl:template match="point">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="distance">
    <cumulDistance>
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(.|parent::*/preceding-sibling::*/distance)"/>
    </cumulDistance>
  </xsl:template>
  
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```